# Fibre Channel CRC Calculation?

Tags: boost, channel, crc, payload

I've been given a task to calculate the CRC value from a Fibre Channel  frame in C++. In order to verify my CRC values are correct, I am checking it against hardware calculated CRC values. Unfortunately I don't know the specific algorithm in which the hardware calculated CRC value is generated. I just have to make sure my software generated CRC values match up with the hardware CRC values.

I've been using the boost::crc_32_type to calculate my CRC values. However, every single CRC value that I get does not match up with any of the hardware calculated CRC values. Any thoughts as to what might be the cause?

What I am also wondering is how the CRC value calculated in a Fibre channel frame? Is it calculated only from the payload or frame header + payload? I can't seem to find a definite answer to this. I've tried calculating both, but still with no success.

Unfortunately, I can't show any of the actual data used for my crc calculations. Basically this the code I've been using to calculate the CRC32:

```
lib::crc_32_type result;
std::vector<uint32_t> payload = frame->payload();

// We have a function that can take a vector<uint32_t> and pass it off to boost::crc_32_type
result(payload);

printf("crc = %08u", result.checksum());
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer to my problem. I'm posting this in case anyone ran into the same issue as I did.

The Fibre channel frame's CRC is calculated based off of the frame header + payload. You have to make sure both the frame header and the payload is stored in big endian before you pass off your data to the boost::crc_32_type for calculation. Below is what I did:

```
#include <boost/crc.hpp>

someLibrary::crc_32_type crc;
FibreChannelFrameObject frame;

FrameHeader fh = frame.header();

std::vector<uint_32> hdr_payload, payload = frame.payload();

// Add entire frame header to hdr_payload
hdr_payload.push_back(fh.word0);
hdr_payload.push_back(fh.word1);
hdr_payload.push_back(fh.word2);
hdr_payload.push_back(fh.word3);
hdr_payload.push_back(fh.word4);
hdr_payload.push_back(fh.word5);

for(auto i = payload.begin(); i != payload.end(); ++i)
{
   hdr_payload.push_back(be32toh(*i));
}

// I have some function that can take in a std::vector<uint32_t> and send it to boost::crc_32_type for calculation
crc(hdr_payload);

printf("crc()   =   %08u", crc.checksum());
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a web search, it appears that the CRC polynomial is CRC32:

```
X^32 + X^26 + X^23 + X^22 + X^16 + X^12 + X^11 + X^10 + X^8 + X^7 + X^5 + X^4 + X^2 + X + 1
```

hex 0x104C11DB7, or in this case for a reflected CRC, hex 0xEDB88320

The CRC calculation is reflected (each data byte is process least significant bit first. I suggest starting with CRC32 from this online calculator:

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html